# Deploying django, postgres, react, nginx app to google app engine

Tags: django, docker, nginx, google-app-engine, docker-compose

I want to deploy my first project on google cloud (didn't had any experience before this project with google cloud). My project is built on django, react, postgresql, nginx. The project is dockerized with a multiple containers and I am using docerk-compose. To my understanding best choice is app engine ( cloud run would be good in case if I had only one container ) cloud compute and kurbernete would be too complicated for my app or as first deployment.

I general my questions is to understand the most robust way to deploy my app. In following description will be some more detailer questions to understand overall concept.

**1. General process deploying**
Most similar setup on online courses I found [London app developer](https://youtu.be/TFsFLzNL5Fk)
for example

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.pd.yml run --rm gcloud sh -c "gcloud app deploy --project my-project"
```

he is running gcloud commands inside container. (I didn't find any similar tutorial/documentation where it's done like this ) Is this common practice to deploy from container?

Here is an other example of deploying multiple apps, but does not involve docker-compose.
[medium url](https://stackoverflow.com)

**2. Nginx vs gunicorn**
In the same London app developer tutorial and google documentation on deployment `app.yaml` entrypoint is set for gunicorn. In my project I am using nginx.
I found some information here, but for me it wasn't well described to understand how it can be modified for my app.
[google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/runtime)

**3. Detailed deployment process.**
When deploying my app I am receiving following error. For me it looks like problem is with entrypoint/nginx set-up.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/flex_await_healthy/flex_await_healthy>2023-05-06T12:18:28.907Z1098.zq.1: Your deployment has failed to become healthy in the allotted time and therefore was rolled back. If you believe this was an error, try adjusting the 'app_start_timeout_sec' setting in the 'readiness_check' section.
```

## docekr-compose

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.pd
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
      - static_volume:/app/staticfiles
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py wait_for_db &&
              python manage.py migrate"
    env_file:
      - ./.env.pd
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=backend.settings.pd
    depends_on:
      - db
    user: "django-user"

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.pd
    volumes:
      - frontend:/frontend/dist
    stdin_open: true
    depends_on:
      - backend
    expose:
      - "5173"

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./config
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/app/staticfiles
      - frontend:/var/www/frontend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend

# db blocked can be removed as is only for local
  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - dev-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=devdb
      - POSTGRES_USER=devuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password123

  gcloud:
    image: google/cloud-sdk:latest
    volumes:
      - gcp-creds:/creds
      - .:/app
    working_dir: /app
    environment:
      - CLOUDSDK_CONFIG=/creds


volumes:
  dev-db-data:
  frontend:
  static_volume:
  gcp-creds:
```

Dockerfile for nginx

```
FROM nginx:1.21-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY  ./nginx/nginx-app.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
# COPY  ./nginx/nginx-app.conf ./app

# Create a simple file to handle health checks. Health checking can be disabled
# in app.yaml, but is highly recommended. Google App Engine will send an HTTP
# request to /_ah/health and any 2xx or 404 response is considered healthy.
# Because 404 responses are considered healthy, this could actually be left
# out as nginx will return 404 if the file isn't found. However, it is better
# to be explicit.
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/nginx/www/_ah && \
    echo "healthy" > /usr/share/nginx/www/_ah/health

CMD ["nginx","-g","daemon off;"]
```

What information could be useful to understand why hatcheck is failing?

Kind regards,

Comment: I'd recommend you to use App Engine Standard which has the lowest maintanence burden https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-app-engine-python3/#0

Comment: If I understand correctly the errors and overall, then my issue ,that my nginx is not set up correctly, but I'm missing information how to do that correctly. This issue would be either way, if flex or standard app engine

Comment: You dont have to deal with nginx and gunicorn (or similar wsgi servers) in AppEngine Standard at all, just the application part (Django in this case)